# Rails time job issue with Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, koala

I have the following code that is executed at a certain time by a cron job.

```
        @user.refresh_facebook_token
        @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@user.oauth_token)
        @graph.put_connections("me", "feed", message: @post.content)
        logger.debug("Posted #{@post.content} at #{@post.buffer_time}")
```

This calls the following code in the user model:

```
def refresh_facebook_token
    if facebook_token_expired?
      # Get the new token
      new_token = facebook_oauth.exchange_access_token_info(self.oauth_token)
      Time.zone = self.time_zone
      # Save the new token and its expiry over the old one
      self.update_attribute(:oauth_token, new_token['access_token']);
      self.update_attribute(:oauth_expires_at, Time.zone.now + new_token['expires'].to_i)
      save
    end
  end

  def facebook_token_expired?
    Time.zone = self.time_zone
    return Time.zone.now > self.oauth_expires_at
  end

  def facebook_oauth
    @facebook_oauth ||= Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
  end
```

What I'm trying to do is refresh the facebook access token if needed before running my cron job so that I can write the post without worrying about expired tokens. However, I get the following error:

```
  40050960     type: OAuthException, code: 190, error_subcode: 463, message: Error validating access token: Session has
expired on Mar 22, 2014 2:00am. The current time is Mar 22, 2014 8:50am. [HTTP 400]
```

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/ (Read Scenario 3 note) I can't make another OAuth call in a cron job? Is there a way to ensure that I'm able to make a post at a certain time without worrying about expired tokens? I'm aware about the 60 day token but that too will expire, and my app may still have to refresh the token if the job is scheduled 61 days in the future.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solution?

Comment: Hey SsouLlesS, after I wrote this question I ended up looking into it and found out that even though the API claimed to have phased out infinite access tokens, the "60-day" tokens I grabbed back from the API were in fact ones that had no expiration date. I don't know if they updated their API to pass back 60-day tokens but back when I wrote this question that wasn't the case. Unfortunately because this meant I didn't need to find a workaround, I never did get the chance to come up with a good solution to my question :\